# how to use a renamed file in another operation in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I want to rename the file and use renamed file in some other operation.
I am trying below which is giving error "./test.sh: line 1: =: command not found"

```
$name = mv file1.txt file2$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000)).txt

echo filename is $name
```

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. [Edit] your post to include the specific error you get. Anyway, you simply need to read the basics about how to get output of one command into a variable; what you did is very much _not_ it.

Comment: paste your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix the errors flagged there. Be sure to include a first line like `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the code you want to realize?

```sh
name="file2$(($(date +%s%N) / 1000000)).txt"

mv file1.txt "${name}"

echo "filename is ${name}"
```